# Where I can ask about "Where (on which site) I can watch specific TV-Show?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've the following question:

[Where I can watch full episodes of British Got Talent?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24645/where-i-can-watch-full-episodes-of-british-got-talent)

which I've asked on Movies & TV SE site, but it was closed. Therefore, can I ask here, or if not (off-topic), then where I can ask the above question?

Comment: On your TV provider's website more then likely.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, I can't ask on meta where I can ask?

Comment: On meta all a downvote means is we don't agree with you.

Comment: As iandotkelly said on your question, ask on chat! The same people are there than on the actual site, but over there, it won't be deleted! There is a chance someone knows the answer.

Comment: It's really off-topic. Thus, +1.

Answer (score 8):

No. Its clearly off topic. Even if there are computers on the show. As someone with non trivial reputation, you should know better than to ask it here.

I think this is *clearly* not the Ewoks we are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

You can not ask such a question anywhere on the StackExchange Q&A network.

If you really have to ask it somewhere on SE, ask it in a chatroom. It's off-topic everywhere because it's about locating specific content, as was mentioned to you on your original question.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping StackExchange Q&A network would cover all the questions.

Comment: Nope, not *every* question can be asked on StackExchange. That's definitely not something they are trying to achieve here.